# backbutton on my android webview

Tags: android, button, webview, back

I tried to add a back button to my android webview but i've got this error:
The method onBackPressed() of type new WebViewClient(){} must override or implement a supertype method

This is my Java file:

```
package sherdle.donald.duck.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
{
WebView webview;

final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,    String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        // do something on back.
        return;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see the edit just copy paste and run it!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), there is no `onBackPressed` method in the `WebViewClient` class. Did you want to Override it on your activity ?
try smthing like this:

```
package sherdle.donald.duck.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
{
WebView webView;

final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,    String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
   }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed (){
        if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
        else super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want my back button works. I'm not good in android, I used a template.

Comment: So i have to move the onBackPressed to another place. Where exactly??

Comment: I changed my @override things in your's but i get the same error.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I needed to change every webView in webview but it wirks fine now!!!!!

Comment: And if I'm using fragment? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 package sherdle.donald.duck.app;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
 {
 WebView webview;

  final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
});

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,    String failingUrl)
    {
        // Handle the error
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

  }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
             if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true)

              webview.goBack();
              else finish();
               break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

And this method should be override in `Activty`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `onkeyDown()` method in your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                mWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Keyevent cannot be resolved to a variable. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Change it to:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

and then use the second answer - works like a charm!